# How to Exit from firebase serve --only functions in Terminal

Tags: terminal, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

In my terminal, I typed:

```
> MacBook-Pro-9:firecast $ firebase serve --only functions
```

I invoke realtime database functions for instance like:

> myDatabaseFunction('old_data')

Then I was done. Is there a way to exit from the running process without having to close the terminal completely?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the following command to end an ongoing process:

<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> (twice) or <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

type "exit" to exit from cli.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).